# XYZ FILES FORMAT is Not working in Potree

Tags: web, point, point-clouds, gis

I have a XYZ files Formats and i want to create there WebGL based point cloud Using [Potree](http://www.potree.org/)  But 
When I try Las files its works Perfectly fine but When i try to Use  Process XYZ Files Formats It NOT WORKS 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Potree Converter 1.5 Cant Process XYZ FILES Although So We have to convert XYZ To las Using **Free OF COST Feature txt2las** of [Lastools](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools)

Then process las file and get my desire result Thanks